# Why does "ls" show folders that the Finder doesn't?

Tags: terminal, finder

I'm using Terminal under ~/Apps.  When I do "ls", I can see a folder called "tempr"; there're files inside of it.  But when I open Apps in the Finder, I can't see the "tempr" folder? Apps look about 95% the same as from Terminal, but there're still some folder differences I can’t figure out.

If I open VSCode for example, File->Open shows the folder in the popup window.

What's going on? I feel like I'm going crazy.

Comment: Actually, `ls -laeO@ ~/Apps | pbcopy` would be even more informative.

Answer (score 4):

Mac OS can hide files in a variety of ways and means.

Simply appending `.` to the start of the filename will by default hide the file. Also macOS Finder will hide files that have a hidden flag attribute.

When you run `ls` you are do not see files beginning with `.` but do see files with the hidden flag. You can try `ls -a` to view all files/folder including those beginning with `.`. To see if there are files with a hidden flag run `ls -lO`.

Furthermore, you can do <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> on the keyboard to toggle visibility of files in the finder.

Comment: Why does VScode show the file?

Comment: Because the VS Code file dialog box chooses to show even hidden files. Probably because programmers often have to deal with files that are normally hidden from the average user.